# Chai - AssertionError: expected BigNumber

Tags: javascript, solidity, chai

I try to test this code:

```
contract Token {
    // Some string type variables to identify the token.
    string public name = "My Hardhat Token";
    string public symbol = "MHT";

    // The fixed amount of tokens, stored in an unsigned integer type variable.
    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000;

    // An address type variable is used to store ethereum accounts.
    address public owner;

    // A mapping is a key/value map. Here we store each account's balance.
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    // The Transfer event helps off-chain applications understand
    // what happens within your contract.
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    /**
     * Contract initialization.
     */
    constructor() {
        // The totalSupply is assigned to the transaction sender, which is the
        // account that is deploying the contract.
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /**
     * A function to transfer tokens.
     *
     * The `external` modifier makes a function *only* callable from *outside*
     * the contract.
     */
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        // Check if the transaction sender has enough tokens.
        // If `require`'s first argument evaluates to `false` then the
        // transaction will revert.
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount, "Not enough tokens");

        // Transfer the amount.
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[to] += amount;

        // Notify off-chain applications of the transfer.
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, amount);
    }

    /**
     * Read only function to retrieve the token balance of a given account.
     *
     * The `view` modifier indicates that it doesn't modify the contract's
     * state, which allows us to call it without executing a transaction.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[account];
    }
}
```

i use this js code

```
    const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("Token contract", function () {
  it("Deployment should assign the total supply of tokens to the owner", async function () {
    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");

    const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy();

    const ownerBalance = await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
    expect(await hardhatToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBalance);
  });
});
```

The ERROR IS:

```
AssertionError: expected BigNumber { value: "1000" } to equal BigNumber { value: "1000" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine for me. Try running `npx hardhat clean` and then try again.

[image]